# A button transitions into a simple email form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that is finished and it's basic with an active and hover css element. I want to make it so when my "Join the Loop" button is clicked it will then change to a simple email form like the one here https://gab.ai/

sorry for my lame explanation. here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/hkr95odp/1/

```css
.up {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color:#FFF;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid #ff0000;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#ff0000;
  font-family:Quicksand;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:10px 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 130px -18px #ff0000;

}
.up:hover {

   background-color: #ff0000;
   color: #fff;

}
.up:active {

}
```

Comment: so... where's the code?

Comment: sorry i was editing the comment. this is my first time asking anything

Comment: What javascript have you tried? If I told you that what you want to do is create the form (like you see in your example) and have it placed hidden under the button until it is clicked, would that make sense to you?

Comment: @Jhecht that makes sense to me, I know what it means but I haven't tried any Javascript at all yet. what confuses me is how to incorporate the Javascript with the button. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by wrapping the signup and signin anchors in span elements to keep things readable. Give the signup anchor an id so we can animate it, and immediately after the signup anchor add a form which is initially hidden.

```
<body>
<header class="header">
  <div class="wrap">
   <span id="animationSandbox" style="display: block;"><h1 class="site__title mega">CONCUR</h1></span>
    <span class="beta subhead">Verifiable &#8226; Public &#8226; News</span>
  </div>
</header><!-- /.site__header -->
    <h5 class="credit">-Product of BRIMM-</h5>
  <div class="sign">
   <span id="signupSpan">
     <a id="signup" href="#" class="up">Join the loop</a>
    <form id="joinform" action="??????" class="join" style="display:none;">
      <label for="email" class="subhead">Email</label>
      <input name="email" style="width: 120px;" class="subhead">  
      <input type="submit" value="Send">  
    </form>
</span> 
   <span>
    <a href="#" class="in">SIGN IN</a>
  </span>   
</div>
  <div id="joinformdiv" class="join" style="display:none;border:1px solid red; padding: 10px;position:absolute;">
  </div>
</body>
```

And modify the css to include the new class which is same as 'up' class but without transition. This is assigned to the form so that it has the same appearance as the button.

```
.join {
  background-color:#FFF;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid #ff0000;
  color:#ff0000;
  font-family:Quicksand;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:10px 10px;
  padding-bottom:12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 130px -18px #ff0000;
}
```

Then include jquery library, and add script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">      </script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signup").on("click", function(e){
      $("#signup").fadeOut(400, function(){
              $("#joinform")
                .css({opacity: 0, display: "inline"}) 
            .animate({opacity: 1},400, function(){ $("#email").focus()})
      })
    })
});
```

What is happening here is that when the signup button is clicked it fades out, then the hidden form has its opacity set to make it invisible and its display set to be inline. This is important because a form is a block element and if w just used fadeIn() it would push the other content down the page. We then use the animate() command to animate the opacity to 1 which makes the element fully visible.

Unlike using position and display absolute to fix the position of the email form over the button, this approach puts the email form inside the same parent element of the button so that scrolling will not cause a problem.

Comment: its working well, only problem is that when i rescale my page the email form moves around and the join the loop button is still there.

Comment: Edited answer to fit your issue.

Comment: only problem is that when I rescale the window after I clicked "join the loop" the email form moves across the page. It works though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is just to replace `DIV` content by `INPUT`You can adjust styling, this is your start point :)

```
  <div class="sign">
    <a href="#" class="up" onClick="this.parentNode.innerHTML='<input />'">Join the loop</a>
    <a href="#" class="in">SIGN IN</a>
  </div>
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hkr95odp/2/

Greets.